# How to convert unicode to ASCII?

Tags: unicode

I must remove Unicode characters from many files (many cpp files!) and I'm looking for script or something to remove these unicode. the files are in many folders!

Comment: What do you mean by "remove"? Literally just remove them and leave the content meaningless? Or make some attempt at, for example, replacing characters like é with e?

Comment: @DavidM: `e` is also a Unicode character.

Comment: @Kerrek SB - yes, I know - but we both know what he means...

Comment: these Unicode characters that I want to remove are in comment! actually I want to sent these codes to Moss (Stanford) and its said that there is unrecognized characters on these files! and its because of some odd comments that my students put on their codes!

Comment: @Amin. You're making me feel quite breathless. Tone down on the exclamation marks, okay?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have it, you should be able to use [iconv](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/libiconv/documentation/libiconv-1.13/iconv.1.html) (the command-line tool, not the C function). Something like this:

```
$ for a in $(find . -name '*.cpp') ; do iconv -f utf-8 -t ascii -c "$a" > "$a.ascii" ; done
```

The `-c` option to `iconv` causes it to drop characters it can't convert. Then you'd verify the result, and go over them again, renaming the ".ascii" files to the plain filenames, overwriting the Unicode input files:

```
$ for a in $(find . -name '*.ascii') ; do mv $a $(basename $a .ascii) ; done
```

Note that both of these commands are untested; verify by adding `echo` after the  `do` in each to make sure they seem sane.

Answer (score 0):

Open the srt file in Gaupol, click on file, click on save as, drop menu for character encoding, select UTF-8, save the file.